# Stripe - Is there a way to get the revenue of a product for current/specific month?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Right now I am creating multiple products with 3 subscription plans. I am looking for a way how to get the monthly revenue for a product.

example:
Product 1  has 1 new (5$) subscription and 2 current subscription for this month. I want to get a total revenue of 15$ for this month for product 1.

I was reading the documentation and I can't seem to find anything about this.

Answer (score 2):

Subscriptions generate Invoices that create Charges, you could list the Charges:

```
await stripe.charges.list(
  {limit: 3}
);
```

Hope that helps!

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list

Comment: Hello thank you for the response! I was thinking if there is a way to get a list from a specific product like in product 1